# Scrapy: No module named 'scrapy.contrib'

Tags: module, scrapy

I've looked everywhere for a solution to this. I didn't used to have a problem calling "from scrapy.contrib..." but now it throws this error.

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.contrib'
```

Posting here as a last resort. Any help here would be extremely welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`scrapy.contrib` has been deprecated for ages now.
It was removed in the 1.6 release of scrapy.

For more details, see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#deprecation-removals

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick reply!! I upgraded my scrapy not long ago that must be why. So is code that uses scrapy.contrib unusable now? Asking because I was implementing the RandomUserAgentMiddleware in my project which makes use of it.  I'm new to scrapy btw.

Comment: There's information in the link I've provided explaining how to find out where the functionality you need has been moved to.

Answer (score 1):

from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

Answer (score 1):

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove contrib and write command as below
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).