# Request is not being proxied through middleware

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script in scrapy to make a request pass through a custom middleware in order for that request to be proxied. However, the script doesn't seem to have any effect of that middleware. When I print `response.meta`, I get `{'download_timeout': 180.0, 'download_slot': 'httpbin.org', 'download_latency': 0.9680554866790771}` which clearly indicates that my request is not passing through the custom middleware. I've used `CrawlerProcess` to run the script.

`spider` contains:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class ProxySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "proxiedscript"
    start_urls = ["https://httpbin.org/ip"]

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.meta)
        print(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    c.crawl(ProxySpider)
    c.start()
```

`middleware` contains:

```
class ProxiesMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://206.189.25.70:3128'
        return request
```

Change that I've made in `settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'proxyspider.middleware.ProxiesMiddleware': 100,
}
```

The following image shows the project hierarchy:
[image]

***What possible change should I bring about to make a proxied request through middleware?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check log output of this line: `[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:` for list of active downloader middlewares. Your middleware should be in the list if it's active.

As far as I remember usage of  `scrapy.contrib` modules deprecated now.
[Scrapy: No module named 'scrapy.contrib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074533/scrapy-no-module-named-scrapy-contrib)

Your code with custom middleware is nearly ready for usage of scrapy command line tool
 `scrapy crawl proxiedscript`.

Hovewer Your crawler process needs to[`read_projects_settings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230147/reading-settings-in-spider-scrapy) first if need to launch scrapy application as script.
or define `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` setting as argument for `CrawlerProcess`:

```
c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
    'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES':{
        #'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,#deprecated in scrapy 1.6
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware':110, #enabled by default
        'proxyspider.middleware.ProxiesMiddleware': 100, 
                              },
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps return `None` instead of a `Request`? Returning a `Request` prevents any other downloader middlewares from running.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.DownloaderMiddleware.process_request

Comment: I just ran my script replacing `return request` with `return None` but still having the same behavior. I even checked it kicking out the return altoghether but no luck.